# How to download PyHook module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried to install PyHook but I'm still getting the error:

> ImportError: No module named 'pyhook'

Please give a me solution. How do I solve this error.

I am making a key-logger program.

```
**code:**
import pythoncom, pyHook, sys, logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'YOURNAME-keylog.txt'
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                        level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(message)s')
    print "Key: ", chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

[Please refer screenshot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5KAc.png)

Comment: If that's the error message, then you must not have installed the module correctly. 

Did you run the `setup.py` ? Are you sure that didn't give any error messages?

Comment: can you check if pyHook is listed in `pip list`?

Comment: please elaborate in more details.thank you

Comment: type `pip list` in command prompt/shell and see if the output is listing pyHook.

Comment: i have tried this but command prompt also give error like Attribute error:'module' object has no attribute 'wraps

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A5KAc.png

Answer (score 2):

First just check which python version you're running, in my case when i type python i'll see:

> Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

That means I'd need to install the 64bits version for python 2.7, the simplest way will be downloading the [pyhook package from this website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook), then just save it on your virtualenv directory (if you're using one) or just in your python folder. Then open a command prompt and go to the path where the package has been downloaded and just type `pip install the_name_of_your_package.whl`, for example, if you're running python 2.7 64bits, you'd type:

> pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

Once that's installed correctly your script should work without problems.

Comment: @VivekTrivedi I've provided more details to my answer, hope that helps. If not, just let me know which step you got stuck with

Comment: when am running program at that time getting error in Python 2.7.12 Shell window like ImportError: No module named pyHook.

Comment: Put the command in your command prompt/terminal window. For windows computers use the command prompt. For Apple computers use the terminal.

Comment: @BPL It might be better(and faster), to just explain to him briefly how to open the command prompt/terminal. Instead of just giving him a link(that could break)

Comment: @VivekTrivedi That means the package pyHook hasn't been installed yet, you need to install it first using the command prompt as explained in the answer. A fast way to open the command prompt on windows is just pressing the key combination win_key+R and then in the opened dialog just typing cmd and press enter

Comment: i have tried this but command prompt also give error like Attribute error:'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'

Comment: Now i need output in same line currently getting out put in new line every keystroke getting in new line.

Answer (score 0):

First of. If you want PyHook your going to have to download it your self, since it is not part of the standard [python library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/) that comes with python. There are my ways you could go about installing it. But the way I recommend is:

**1**. Download PyHook from [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) page. **Make sure to get the download that matches your version of python and your bit number(32 or 64)**.

**2**. Next in your command prompt/terminal window type:

> pip install [full path and name of .whl file]

This command tells pip to install PyHook for. In my case I typed:

> pip install C:\pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`

After doing this your script should run without any problems. If you do encounter any problems using this method, check and see if your installed the right version of python and the correct bit number.

Comment: getting error like 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'

Comment: Please post the full error that you are getting. And make sure that the only  module not working/importing is PyHook. You may have multiple problems.

Comment: First i have open IDEL(Python GUI) then take new file and write program for keylogger and the run via F5 and then getting error like this.

Comment: Once you get the error, copy and paste it into your question. You can do that by clicking edit button under your question.

Comment: please images which i have attached.

Comment: Did you make sure to install the correct version that matches your version of python, and you downloaded the one with the correct bit number for your computer?

Comment: Yes sir install properly with 32 bit.

Comment: What about correct version of python. Mines is python 3.5, however, your could be different.

Comment: yes really thank you so much for help finally done my issue it is problem with like win32.so i have solve it.

Comment: Now i need output in same line currently getting out put in new line every keystroke getting in new line.